# Assign threads to folders in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible in Thunderbird to move a thread from the Inbox to another folder - say folder ToDo -  and then have replies for that thread be moved automatically in the ToDo folder?

I'm interested in a solution which works without manual intervention for each new thread - so no filter per discussion thread. It does not have to be applied instantly as new message arrive - a delay of 1-2 minutes is fine, and it does not have to work for all folders - if I can get Inbox and ToDo to sync like this it's fine.

---

Using Mozilla Thunderbird 3.0 Beta 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now available with Thunderbird 3, in *Copies and Folders/Place replies in the folder of the message being replied to*:

[image: settings]

Answer (score 2):

The [Thunderbird Conversations](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/) extension is probably as close as you're going to get.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's interesting, but I'm really looking for the 'sticky folders' option, as the others are more or less there in 3.0 final.